# Installing apps on TCL Smart TV

Tags: smart-home, smart-tv

I have this 43 inch UHD TCL 43R500 TV. But I am struggling to Install 3rd party apps on it. So it have a build in App Store `TV4` but that doesn't have any good app.

What I have tried is:

- To copy the .apk file in Pen Drive and try installing from it. Doesn't work.
- To Use ES File Manager, but it doesn't find the TV.

Is there a way to access the ROM of the device and save files there ? or any other way to install few useful apps ?

Usually it is connected with T-Cast. Or is found as a DLNA device in LocalCast or Screen Cast apps on Phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. I have the 50 inch model with the same crappy TV4 apps. (COMPLETE GARBAGE) TCL NEEDS to be embarrassed by loading such garbage. The only option is to either purchase an android box (NVIDA Shield) or some other external streaming device like a Roku or Firestick.  Our "smart" tvs are forced to remain DUMB.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Marc!  It would be awesome if you could [edit] this answer including a bit more info, such as how you figured out that you can't.  If you have any sources you could link for further reading and quotes from others, it would also be really nice.  Thanks!